# Can I add Custom Fields to Stripe Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am wondering if I can add kinds of custom fields on my Stripe checkout form like this, This works I've tested it but not about any security things or compaitability issues.

```
<form action="testpayments.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Product 1" name="p1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Product 2" name="p2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="fname">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="KEYHERE"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Website name"
    data-description="Order Price"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true"
    data-currency="USD">
  </script>
</form>
```

This way once the Stripe script generates a Token for me, I will be able to post details such as what products were sold etc to my server and then process it from there.

Will this work without any issues or security holes? If not how should I post user details and sold product details to my own server.

Thank you

PS: This is going to be a PHP Based script in the backend

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: This should work fine without the need for the custom integration. I do something similar to pass size and color selections to my PHP code, which allows me to include that information in email notifications. As long as you are not passing credit card information outside of the Stripe script, I don’t see any security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add custom details through the [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#metadata) part of the charge API (or any other API for that matter).

In general, when you deal with payments, just make sure you don't send any card details to your server, only the token you get back from Stripe.js.